# Manipulate XML into MySQL database via Django

Tags: python, mysql, xml, django

I have the following two models:

```
class StraightredTeam(models.Model):
    teamid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    teamname = models.CharField(max_length=36)
    teamcode = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    teamshortname = models.CharField(max_length=24)
    currentteam = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()

    def natural_key(self):
        return self.teamshortname

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'straightred_team'

class StraightredFixture(models.Model):
    fixtureid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    soccerseason = models.IntegerField(db_column='soccerSeason')  # Field name made lowercase.
    home_team = models.ForeignKey('straightred.StraightredTeam', db_column='hometeamid', related_name='home_fixtures')
    away_team = models.ForeignKey('straightred.StraightredTeam', db_column='awayteamid', related_name='away_fixtures')
    fixturedate = models.DateTimeField()
    fixturestatus = models.CharField(max_length=24)
    fixturematchday = models.IntegerField()
    hometeamscore = models.IntegerField()
    awayteamscore = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'straightred_fixture'
```

The following website offers up soccer fixtures / results in an xml format as follows:

NOTE:  THIS SITE SEEMS TO BE TEMPORARILY DOWN! SORRY.

http://api.football-data.org/alpha/soccerseasons/398/fixtures

I am interested in understanding the best way of manipulating the xml file into the database models shown above.

I am assuming some sort of loop but I wondered if anyone could point me in the right direction or link to an example.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, many thanks, Alan.

Comment: Use a python module to parse xml, for example: http://lxml.de/ or http://effbot.org/zone/element-index.htm. Then take the extracted data and store in your model.

Comment: Many thanks, will try this first thing in the morning :)

Comment: It worked a treat, but I can't accept it as an answer :/